# PostgreSQL Server Start-up Error on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql

Every time I open a new terminal and start postgres server with `pg_ctl start -l log` it returns the following message:

```
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

The only thing that worked for me is setting up the environment variables again with:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:$PATH
export PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/data
```

But I don't want to setup the variables every time I open a new terminal. Am I using the wrong command? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Could you guys help me to solve this?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but one about basic operating system administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar challenge. I think this is peculiar to running WSL on Windows.

To solve the `no database directory specified`, you would have to initialize another cluster in the bin directory of the postgres directory already installed and create a database.

```
initdb test
createdb test
```

To start a server, you must pass a database to command (the command should be entered in the present directory, if you run outside that direction then provide a path to the database)

```
pg_ctl start test -l log
```

or

```
pg_ctl -D test -l logfile start
```

For the second error message, I experience the same always whenever I start a new terminal session. So I came up with an easier way (I am not recommending this but it saves time).
I created a file `.bashrc` and saved the commands inside that file and executed the following:

```
chmod a+x .bashrc
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and start the server using `pg_ctl` on Debian/Ubuntu.  The simplest option is to start the default installation with `sudo service postgresql start`.

Debian/Ubuntu provides the `pg_ctlcluster` command.  This program controls the postgres server for a particular cluster. It essentially wraps
the `pg_ctl` command. It determines the cluster version and data path and calls the right
version of `pg_ctl` with appropriate configuration parameters and paths.

You have to start this program as the user who owns the database cluster or as root.

```
# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
# pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
# pg_ctlcluster 12 main status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 3287)
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"
#
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.bashrc` file is a shell script that gets executed every time you open a new terminal. It is typically located in your home directory. You can use `ls -la` command to check.

To set environment variables permanently, you can add the export commands for the variables to your `.bashrc` file. For example, to set the PGDATA and PATH environment variables, you can open the `.bashrc` file in a text editor (such as nano or vi), and add your commands at the end of the file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:$PATH
export PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/data
```

[image]
*My Scenario*

After saving the changes, restart your terminal. The PGDATA and PATH environment variables should now be set **automatically** every time you open a new terminal.